# Partial Fraction Decomposition

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, mathematical-modeling, partial-fractions

I have an equation related to the Grompertz Growth Curve that has the form:

$$ \frac{dP}{dt} = k_L P(t)(M - P(t)) $$

$K_L = \frac{1}{70} $ and $M = 100$

re arranging this we have

$$ \frac{dP}{P(t)(M - P(t))} = \frac{1}{70} dt $$

L.H.S. can be re written as

$$\frac{dP}{P(t)(M - P(t))} = \frac{A}{P(t)} + \frac{B}{(M - P(t))} $$

From this we can see that $A = \frac{1}{100} \rightarrow AM = 1, A = \frac{1}{M}$

and $-A + B = 0 $ which implies that $ B = A $, so $ B = \frac{1}{100} $

We now have two separate equations, but I am running into a problem. How do I integrate a function?

I have

$$ \frac{1}{100} \bigg( \int \frac{dP}{P(t)} - \int \frac{dP}{ P(t) - M } \bigg) 
 = \frac{1}{70} \int dt$$

This is where I get lost and do not know how to do it. I know that the integral of $\frac{1}{x}$ is ln|x|, but I do not see how that helps me as I have a function in the denominator rather than a variable. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should read the integrals as $\int \frac{1}{P}dP$. Don't think of it as a function (or if you want to be technical use integration by substitution, and use that for differentiable $P$ we have that $dP(t) = P'(t)dt$).

Comment: So would it just be $\frac{1}{100}\bigg(ln|P| - ln|P - M | \bigg) = \frac{1}{70}t $?

Comment: Yes that would be correct.

Comment: Okay thank you, I just thought that since I was dealing with a population "equation" that I had to treat P as such. Looking back at my document it does denote it as P, and my prof. is very specific on notation. Should have caught this. Thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the integrals were with respect to time, you were stuck, but the variable of integration is the function $P$ itself, so you can use the rule of $ \int \frac{1}{x} dx = \ln |x| $

$$ \ln P - \ln (P-M) = \frac{10}{7}t + c $$
$$ \ln \frac{P}{P-M} = \frac{10}{7}t + c $$
$$ \frac{P}{P-M} = e^c \cdot e^{\frac{10}7 t} = A  e^{\frac{10}7 t}$$
$$ P = A  e^{\frac{10}7 t} P  - A  e^{\frac{10}7 t} M $$
$$ P (1 -  Ae^{\frac{10}7 t}) = -MA e^{\frac{10}7 t}$$
$$ P = \frac{-MA  e^{\frac{10}7 t}}{1-A e^{\frac{10}7 t}} $$

Comment: Did you forget a $ + C$ in your e, also where does the$A$ come from?

Comment: C is a general constant, so $e^c$ will be a general constant, let's call it $A$

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for taking the time to reply!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: I have another question, I am given a statement that says that this initial population is 10 and my M is 100 units. Will this still work? I have a similar equation that I am comparing this to and when I had a $C$ I solved for it by letting t = 0. This made the left hand side some initial population $P_0$ (10) . From what I can see if I were to approach it the same way I will get an error as $ln\frac{P}{P - M} = C < 0 $ this gives an error because I believe the domain of ln{x} cannot be negative. How do I get it in the form where I can use the initial population, or is it not important?

Comment: Or can I not approach it the same way? For this equation I clearly use Partial Decomp, but the other equation I used Diff Eq methods, specifically separable equations.